# Array elements not returning the results but passes in match condition

Tags: karate

Attempt to print elements of array in JSON does not appear to work in Karate DSL - Want to understand if I missed something here?

Trying to run the section of the JSON Arrays described in https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-arrays

```
Scenario: Test
    Given def cat =
  """
  {
    name: 'Billie',
    kittens: [
      { id: 23, name: 'Bob' },
      { id: 42, name: 'Wild' }
    ]
  }
  """
  * print ('\n')
  * print ('printing all kittens - working')
  * print cat.kittens
  * print ('printing all id of kittens - not working')
  * print cat.kittens[*].id
```

when executed as `java -jar karate-0.9.0.jar test.feature` returns result as

```
23:30:29.778 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration: could not find or read file: classpath:karate-config.js
23:30:29.893 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]

23:30:29.899 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] printing all kittens - working
23:30:29.921 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Wild"
  }
]

23:30:29.935 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] printing all id of kittens - not working
23:30:29.944 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]
23:30:30.022 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 1 of 1: test.feature
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: test.feature
report: target\test.json
scenarios:  1 | passed:  1 | failed:  0 | time: 0.1339
---------------------------------------------------------
Karate version: 0.9.0
======================================================
elapsed:   1.28 | threads:    1 | thread time: 0.13
features:     1 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.10
scenarios:    1 | passed:     1 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

But I am not seeing the id elements being printed out

- Is this expected behaviour?
- How to achieve this - can this be done only by setting this to temp variable using  `* def temp = cat.kittens[*].id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` statement supports *only* JavaScript and not JsonPath:

```
* def ids = $cat.kittens[*].id
* print ids
```